# Textarea - Change background of specific line

Tags: javafx

I would like to change the background color of a specific line in a TextArea in a Javafx application.

I have searched many places, but I have a hard time finding anything to proceed.
I wonder if anyone have had the same problem or have an idea of how this could be done?

Comment: Could you post an example here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaFX Multiple colors in textarea (JavaFX 8)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202828/javafx-multiple-colors-in-textarea-javafx-8)