# JavaFX Alert with multiple colors

Tags: css, javafx, alert

I have a program that at some point (may) displays two warnings - one about errors - those are in red, and one about warnings - those are in orange.

I wonder however if there is a way - using css - to have just one warning with some text red and some text orange.

Here is an example of what I want to achieve (the two can be separated into "sections"):

```
RED ERROR1
RED ERROR2
RED ERROR3
ORANGE WARNING1
ORANGE WARNING2
```

I've seen some answers pointing to `RichTextFX` [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23203211/4903564), however I don't see (or don't know) how that could apply to generic Alerts. Is that even possible, without writing some custom `ExpandedAlert` class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Alert` class inherits from [`Dialog`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html), which provides a pretty rich API and allows arbitrarily complex scene graphs to be set via the `content` property.

If you just want static text with different colors, the simplest approach is probably to add labels to a `VBox`; though you could also use more complex structures such as `TextFlow` or the third-party `RichTextFX` mentioned in the question if you need.

A simple example is:

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    private final Random rng = new Random();

    private void showErrorAlert(Stage stage) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        int numErrors = 2 + rng.nextInt(3);
        int numWarnings = 2 + rng.nextInt(3);
        VBox errorList = new VBox();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= numErrors ; i++) {
            Label label = new Label("Error "+i);
            label.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red; ");
            errorList.getChildren().add(label);
        }
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= numWarnings ; i++) {
            Label label = new Label("Warning "+i);
            label.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: orange; ");
            errorList.getChildren().add(label);
        }
        alert.getDialogPane().setContent(errorList);
        alert.initOwner(stage);
        alert.show();
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Button showErrors = new Button("Show Errors");
        showErrors.setOnAction(e -> showErrorAlert(stage));
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(showErrors);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

which gives this result:

[image]